# How to expand method to other class in different file using typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a class `Client` in `client.ts`. And in `patch.ts`, I want to add some methods to `Client` class.

```
import {Client} from './client'

// How to do to add a method to Client
```

I tried `Client.prototype.someMethod`. But a type error occur.

I tried using interface merge.

```
declare module '../client' {
  interface Client {
    someMethod(): any
  }
}

Client.prototype.someMethod = function() { return void 0 }
```

It works. But so ugly...

And I have many patch files, such as `patch1.ts`, `patch2.ts`, `patch3.ts`. I want to only patch `Client` class. And other file can import `Client` class to use all patched methods.

Any other way to do that?

Comment: Don't work on the prototype. Create a ConcreteClient that implements the Client-interface implementing the `Client` interface. That concrete implementation then has its specific implementation of `someMethod`. Also: don't type for `any`. Be specific or use generics. It seems like you need to look up OOP paradigm.

Comment: What is in those patch files? What do you want to patch and *why*. You are still only explaining your attempted solution. Why can't you create one class implementing an interface? And use that one as an import in other files? What is your goal?

Comment: Maybe you are missing the concept of `export` and `import` within typescript. See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't work on the prototype. TypeScript adds [object oriented approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html), so I'd advise you to stick with it.

You have an interface, that's but a contract. Any class implementing it must fullfill it.

```
interface Client {
    someMethod(): number
}
```

An concrete or abstract class can implement that interface and has to provide the actual implementation:

```
class ConcreteClient implements Client {
    someMethod(): number {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You can instantiate that class and work with on the object's method:

```
const result = new ConcreteClient().someMethod(); // returns 0;
```

Comment: @XGHeaven Please expand your question with what you actually want to achieve. Your problem appears to be a  [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and I find it hard to understand what you are aiming for.